# Codieum extension fails in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, windows-11

I installed the Visual Studio extension for Codeium.

My company PC runs Windows 11 Version 23H2 (Build 22631.2715).

Visual Studio fails to start the language server and Codeium generates the following error message:

> Starting language server LanguageServer.StartAsync: Failed to start
> the language server; Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
> (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for
> this OS platform.    at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo)    at CodeiumVS.LanguageServer.d__20.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\Users\rahul\source\repos\CodeiumVisualStudio\CodeiumVS\LanguageServer\LanguageServer.cs:line
> 353 Codeium Extension for Visual Studio

Google searches only lead to solutions concerning vs code.
What seems to be obvious is that it is a platform detection problem betwen x86 and x64.

How can I install the correct language server for x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a high chance that the issue originated from an error during the download or extraction of the language server. You could try to resolve this by navigating to the `%appdata%\.codeium` directory and removing all folders that begin with `language_server_v` to force a re-download.

This issue should be fixed in the [PR #31](https://github.com/Exafunction/CodeiumVisualStudio/pull/31) but it hasn't been released yet.

If the issue persists, please try to download the *(correct version of the)* language server manually from [Codeium official repo](https://github.com/Exafunction/codeium/releases) and extract the .exe file to its according folder. For example, download [v1.6.10](https://github.com/Exafunction/codeium/releases/tag/language-server-v1.6.10) for the current latest version and extract the executable to `%appdata\.codeium\language_server_v1.6.10\language_server_windows_x64.exe`

Comment: Removing the Folder starting with _language_server_v_ did the trick, thank you.